# How to tell what row a db table is reading from

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to determine the row a set of data has been collected from in a DataTable?

I currently have this code

```
                    expression = "date = '" & numericYear & "-" & doubleMonth & "-20'"


                foundRows = dbTable.Select(expression)
                For count = 0 To foundRows.Length - 1
                    tableRow =
                    MessageBox.Show(dbTable.Rows(count).Item(5).ToString())

                Next count
```

The issue is the messagebox shows row 0 then 1 then 2 etc. How can i get it to show the row being read from the Data Table? For example if the event being read is on row 52 of the data table how would i tell that?

Comment: Only if you have a unique primary key.  The primary key value will be one of the fields in the row.

Comment: The ordinal row in the DataTable is rarely of interest because it likely has no relation to the DB.  The PK is *the* unique identifier, but it too has no bearing on ordinal postion depending on how the data is ordered and/or filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `indexof` method:

```
foundRows = dbTable.Select(expression)
For count = 0 To foundRows.Length - 1
    rowIndex = dbTable.Rows.IndexOf(foundRows(count))
    MessageBox.Show("Row " & cstr(rowIndex) & " " & foundRows(count).Item(5).ToString())
Next count
```